# Picking random cells based on previous random cell selection in Excel

Tags: random, excel-formula, match

This formula works well to return a random traveldestination1 value if it does find a match for C1 in the moderange range.  It goes to #N/A otherwise:

```
  =IF(MATCH(C1,moderange1,0),INDEX(traveldesination1,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(traveldesination1))),"nope")
```

How can I improve the formula to search another moderange range (non-adjacent) if a match for C1 is not found in moderange1  (it returns #N/A) (or moderange2  or moderange3  etc...)?  It never actually gets to the point of displaying “nope” in this current formula so any code I add there doesn’t get used.

If it doesn't find a match in moderange1, I want it to search moderange2 and if it finds a match there, it should pick a random from traveldestination2 and so on.

Comment: i think the `IF` statement that you want cannot be (easily) done using excel-formula. you will have to write VBA code. In VBA, this should be fairly easy to get to.

Comment: Hi - yes, VBA will definitely be much easier, but I have to keep the workbook macro-free and thus use formulas instead of VBA code....

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to figure it out! - using nested IFNA conditions did the trick:

```
=ifna(ifna(ifna(code as above),next range's code, next range's code),"not found")
```

Comment: Excel formula only work for limited number of recursion. As we are forced to do it, the formula usually look horribly long. Hence, consider using Names to make the formula look shorter. It is also easier to maintain.